# Cannot render a React App in Ruby on Rails after authentication

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, webpack-dev-server

I'm using Rails 6 with webpacker and react. I've set a basic authentication system that is redirecting the user to the home page after a successfully authentication. 
This is some code from the Sessions Controller

```
def create
    user= User.find_by_email(params[:email])
    if user && user.authenticate(params[:password])
      session[:user_id] = user.id 
      redirect_to root_url, notice: "Logged in"
    else
      flash.now[:alert] = "Email or password is invalid"
      render "new"
    end
  end
```

On the home page I've mounted a React App that should be loaded when the user is logged in but to mount the react app I have to reload the home page a second time. 
So the user authentication has no problem but I cannot render the React App immediately after being redirected to the home page. 
This is how the app is mounted

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  ReactDOM.render(
    <Hello name="React" />,
    document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('div')),
  )
})
```

How can avoid a manually reloading of the page? Thanks

Comment: So its not an issue with your ruby code rather how you have setup your SPA / react code

Comment: I've added the setup of the React app